# Trying to access Linksys WRT54GL remotely

Tags: router, remote-access

I am trying to allow access (to me) remotely for this new Router.  I do know the IP address but I think I need to know the default port to use.  How can I find out the default port for this?  Right now, I am not at the location of the router so do I have to wait until I am actually sitting in fron of the router to enable this feature?

If not, how do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably have to enable remote access from wan (outside).
Most routers only allow administrative access from the inside by default.

Answer (score 1):

As Nifle said, you'll have to enable remote access.  Also, people have a misconception that you can access your router by using the internal IP address (typically 192.168.0.1) over the WAN which is incorrect.  You'll have to find your external IP address.  A simple method is to go to www.whatismyip.com

Comment: No, it's 192.168.1.1. I would like to know where you got this information... Linksys default is 192.168.1.1, and you can only access it via private IP address until you have enabled remote administration. Show me a reliable source that agrees with you (non forumn) and I will take off my -1.

Comment: +1, because guessing wrong on a single octet of an IP doesn't seem like its worth a -1.  (other consumer model routers do use the .0.1, just not linksys.)  The main content of your answer was correct. You need to enable remote access.  -Protip.. Sign up for some service like dyndns.org, and then you don't have to remember your IP.  And change those default passwords!

Comment: @Brian, how is his answer correct at all!?!? You don't administer you router for first time use from outside the network of the router. That's absurd for you to agree with his if you have the slightest bit of knowledge about networking. Not trying to be mean, but when someone is totally wrong, they are totally wrong. And no, I did not -1 him just for one octet being off. Your wrong. Please read the ENTIRE comment.

Comment: David is obviously new to the field.

Answer (score 0):

You need a port to remotely manage your router. To setup remote management of the router, log on to the router while you are inside the network of the router. The router's IP address is probably 192.168.1.1. The credentials are probably admin (user name) and password (for the password). Once your are there, look around for remote management, and check the box (most likely), then you may need to select a port to use for remote management.

You also need to set up a port to manage computers under your router. for instance, if you would like to access a computer at 192.168.1.2, you would go into your router settings and set up a port forward for 192.168.1.2 with port :555 (random number). Now, if you go to your public IP address 172.155.26.73:555 (random IP address with random port number) you will go to the machine with the private IP address of 192.168.1.2. If you just go to 172.155.26.73:### (Public IP address with remote router management port), you will access the router.

If you need any more help, let me know!